# How to calculate Pull ups count using iPhone accelerometer?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

We are working on one health based application in iPhone in which we need to find the Pull-ups count for the user. We need to do same as it is working in the “Runtastic Pull Ups - Workout, Trainer & Rep Counter” app available on AppStore.

App URL:

- https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/runtastic-pull-ups-workout/id570182252?mt=8

We are trying to calculate the Pull-Ups count using accelerometer in iPhone device. But not getting proper solution to count the pull-ups data correctly. Can anyone tell where we are wrong and how to count the correct data like Runtastic Pull Ups app?

Comment: Can you share what you currently have (code) and let us know what the expected results are and what you get?

Comment: I have to get device up down count by using accelerometer.

Comment: @Hannes as asking for the code that you have written to try to implemmented this yourself. You question now looks like code request which is frowned upon and might get you question downvoted.

Comment: `motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;
    
   [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
    {

 }];

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    NSLog(@"acceleration.y = %f",acceleration.y);
    NSLog(@"acceleration.x = %f",acceleration.x);
    NSLog(@"acceleration.z = %f",acceleration.z);
}`

Comment: @rckoenes I think asking for code that doesn't work is safe. I just wanted to know what he already tried, there are enough people asking for full solutions without writing a single line of code before.

Comment: @Parthpatel1105 using the raw accelerometer won't produce great results. You should have a look at high pass filtering your data. There is a sample project from apple that applies that to accelerometer data: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @Hannes I had already checked that apple sample code. But i have to measure only Y axis changes. And also with up down device it does not give proper Y value that i can identify changes.